# How can I access a column of a table stored in a variable in DAX

Tags: ssas, dax, ssas-tabular

Assuming the following code :

```
VAR tableRow = FILTER( CustomDateTable; Now() >= [StartDate] && Now() <= [EndDate] )  

VAR singleValue = MINX( tableRow ; [Col1] )
```

We retrieve a single row from the table named `CustomDateTable` and we then want to extract the value of the column named `Col1`. Because it's the only row, `Col1` should containt a single value.

I use `MINX()` to do that but I feel like it probably not the most efficient way of doing it.

How can I extract a single row of a table with a custom Filter, store it in a variable for further use, and then extract a sigle value from one of it columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be `VAR singleValue = SUMMARIZE( tableRow ; [Col1] )`

Another one is `VAR singleValue = CALCULATE ( VALUES ( [Col1] ); tableRow )`

Comment: Thank you, `SUMMARIZE` work well and it the shorter version. But it still a little weird, by reading the definition on this function on MSDN I wouldn't have though it would do that.